# Travis CI - Unable to remove port forward Error executing adbExec

Tags: appium, travis-ci, appium-android

I am trying to setup automated tests for an android app using Appium (npm version) but I keep getting the error

`[UiAutomator2] Did not get confirmation UiAutomator2 deleteSession worked; Error was: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Trying to proxy a session command without session id
[UiAutomator2] Unable to remove port forward 'Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/usr/local/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp\:8200' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'error: listener 'tcp:8200' not found'; Code: '1''`

I have looked around google for ages but havnt been able to find any solution that has actually worked for me, so far totalling 50 failed builds.

If i run the commands on my local machine it works fine but within travis I have no such luck unfortunately. I am new to setting up appium so it could be something minor im not understanding.

[A gist of my travis.yml file is here](https://gist.github.com/danwoodbury/787a23bd3aeed686df59fde37ce97d44)

Distribution:

`Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`tcp:8200` is not forwarded and there should be no forwards.

try with `adb forward --remove-all`, when not knowing which port it is

... if it's even required to remove any forward.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the logs, I understand that the emulator is not ready to allow UiAutomator to get deployed properly.

So to make sure that emulator is ready, you can use `avdLaunchTimeout` and `avdReadyTimeout` by passing `60000` ms to both in your desired capabilities.

Once the emulator is ready, you won't get this error.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately this didnt work. The default for those capabilities is 60000 anyway so I put in a huge number too but its the same issue. This is baffling me

Comment: Can you try removing the lines from your travis yml file where you start the emulator and wait for it to load? Also add `avd` capability to your desired capabilities with Emulator name. This will instruct Appium to start the emulator for you and avdReadyTimeout and avdLaunchTimeout will come into work.

Comment: If you still can't figure out, check out my framework's azure pipeline yaml file. https://github.com/WasiqB/coteafs-appium/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml

Comment: great thanks, there a few things I cantry there. Is there a chance you could share with me the capabilities you are setting so I can match them up? Im very new to appium and the girl who wrote the tests dosnt know anything about CI so im helping out, or trying to anyway

Comment: If you want, you can try my framework (link already shared above). The capabilities are stored in yml file and dynamically used by the framework.